# How can I make the Tide SDK console font larger

Tags: tidesdk

On Ubuntu the font in the TideSDK console is pretty small. How do I go about changing it? Is there a CSS file or something I need to alter?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the TideSDK build instructions for Ubuntu](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/TideSDK-Build-Ubuntu-12.04), TideSDK is a GTK2 application.

Thus, you *might* be able to control the font by setting the default GTK font.

This answer will tell you how to do that.  NOTE: if the application explicitly sets a font in code, then this whole answer does not apply.

There might be a way to change the default GTK font setting via some GUI in Ubuntu, but I usually use the rc file method.

That means creating settings files in your home directory that GTK reads.

Here are the GTK related files in my own home directory.

```
hobbes@metalbaby:~$ ls -al .gtk*
-rw-r--r-- 1 hobbes hobbes  37 Feb 14 11:49 .gtkrc-1.2-gnome2
-rw-r--r-- 1 hobbes hobbes  37 Feb 14 11:49 .gtkrc-2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 hobbes hobbes 107 May 20 11:45 .gtkrc.hobbes
```

And the contents of each file:

#### .gtkrc-1.2-gnome2

```
include '/home/hobbes/.gtkrc.hobbes'
```

#### .gtkrc-2.0

```
include '/home/hobbes/.gtkrc.hobbes'
```

#### .gtkrc.hobbes

```
style "terminus"
{
font_name = "Terminus"
}
widget_class "*" style "terminus"
gtk-font-name = "Terminus 8"
```

Note the use of `include` to apply the same settings to more than one version of GTK application.  On my system, this makes emacs and Eclipse use the Terminus 8 font in menus and dialog boxes.

Arch Linux has a wiki page that has a lot of [generic information about GTK](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B) settings.  I don't think that this was the resource I used when creating those files, but nonetheless it is a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to TideSDK Developer as the console, it is simply an app created and bundled using TideSDK. To edit the font size, just adjust the CSS within the app and rebuild it using TideSDK. You can get the sources from https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-Developer, make the changes, import to your existing Developer, build, and you are done. TideSDK Developer is getting a bit old.

You may not be aware of the new product we are launching shortly. Myself and other core talent from TideSDK have been focusing our efforts on TideKit that has a brand new CLI, app and services to support builds. You can look for the new site to appear at http://www.tidekit.com and follow our developments at http://twitter.com/tidekit. Unlike TideSDK that was only for desktop, TideKit is our new develop once, deploy everywhere solution for developing for mobile, web and desktop from a single source of code in JavasScript. TideSDK apps will be able to be migrated if you have existing code. Here is our promo video: http://youtu.be/aE7gN-d0GhU